# unable to install using msiinstaller

Tags: windows-installer

My windows server 2012 was infected with a malware and it was cleaned with an anti-malware. But now when I try to install an antivirus, it wouldn't allow me to install the application. I had contacts with the vendors of the antivirus and they told me to reinstall the msi instller. I checked on the net and version 4.5 is available but not 5.0 which is my version of msi installer.

I have tried all the repairing solutions on the net on the msi installer but still throwing an error.

> The installation of the antivirus has failed (0x80041f09). Contact your system administrator

Any idea how to re install msi installer? or any other solution.

Thnaks

Comment: consider posting the question in the  [SysAdmin sub-form](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: please read the [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section

Comment: okay. Sorry. will re post it in the sysAdmin.